# select folders (not files) with leading "_" (underscore) symbols in terminal

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sh, mv

I'm trying to run through folders and subfolders (only, no files can be altered) in a given directory *which have leading underscores* and remove those leading underscores. I'm planning on accomplishing this with a simple shell script:

```
for folder in ./_* do
  mv "$folder" "${folder:1}"
done
```

The above script doesn't work yet to specification for two reasons which I'm trying to correct here:
- one, the "./_*" does not work like it should, either throwing an error (`./_*: No such file or directory`) or selecting folders which *do not* have leading underscores too.
- two, it does not specify folders only...is there an option for the `mv` command which can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all folders starting with underscore use this `find`:

```
find . -type d -name '_*'
```

And to remove `_` use:

```
find . -type d -name '_*' -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; mv "$f" "${f:1}" - {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) recursively :

```
shopt -s globstar

for dir in **/_*/; do
    mv "$dir" "${dir:1}"
done
```

Comment: Note the trailing `/` in the pattern, which is what filters out non-directories from the results.